# Parse year from SQL Date

Tags: java, sql

I'm currently writing a Java app that interfaces with a MySQL database.
My problem is that I'm trying to write a function that fills a JComboBox with the unique year-values registered in the database.
I could use UNIQE on the date-field in the SQL query, but that would only exclude some of the dates, not all-but-one-date-per-year.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(yourDateColumn) FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [year](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function